# SCSS variable content inside apostrophes

Tags: css, variables, sass, apostrophe

```
@mixin f1($color1, $color2){
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='$color1', endColorstr='$color2',GradientType=0);
}
```

What i want to do is escape the apostrophe's ability of turning $color1 into a string.
startColorstr='$color1' into startColor1str='#000000'.

```
@mixin f1($color1, $color2){
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=+"'"+$color1+"'"+, endColorstr=+"'"+$color2+"'"+,GradientType=0);
}
```

this didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently i had to add the variable inside brackets like '{$color}' but still that wouldnt work alone.
i had to also add a '#' (hash) as well like '#{$color}' (even though i was passing the value of "#333" in the mixin, it still required the #

So the result looks something like this:

```
@mixin f1($color1,$color2){
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#{$color1}', endColorstr='#{$color2}',GradientType=0);
}
```